# how to mount a filesystem without a mount point

Tags: filesystems, mount, automounting

In Ubuntu 14.04.3 inserting my SD card causes it to be automounted to a mount point that does not exist.  **How can *I* do this?**

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  30780420   2269796  28510624   8% /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS
laptop2/root /root 9# umount /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS
laptop2/root /root 10# ls -ld /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS
ls: cannot access /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS: No such file or directory
laptop2/root /root 11# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS
mount: mount point /media/admin/backup-PROJECTS does not exist
laptop2/root /root 12#
```

Comment: What do you mean by “causes it to be automounted to a mount point that does not exist”? If it is actually automounted, then by definition the directory will exist, at least while the card is mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost always need a directory to use a mount point.

The two main exception are

- removable device (where udev `mkdir` and `rmdir` for you)
- automount using nfs `/net/foo` dir. (e.g. when you cd /net/foo, automount will scan host foo for exported dir, create dir and bind mount)

Comment: You **always** need a directory to use a mount point. There's software that creates the directory for you, but the directory has to exist for the mount point to be set up, and it can't be removed as long as the mount point is active.

Comment: @Gilles I agree, that why I use the word 1: mkdir ... for you 2: automount will ... create dir

Answer (score 1):

The mount point is created by `udev` when it senses the card is inserted, and is destroyed when it is unmounted. You cannot mount to a directory that does not exist. Neither can the system, but the system doesn't have to slow itself down long enough to tell you it created the mount point before and let you "press any key to acknowledge" before actually doing the mount.